# Python code takes too much time to run

Tags: python, for-loop, replace, scripting

The problem I was given is to change all "o" with "ko" and "k" with "ok" for 1000 times starting with "ok", then count how many consecutive o's there are. The code slows significantly once it reaches double digits and I'm unsure of what to do to refactor my code.

```
import string
y ="ok"
z = ""
for c in range(1000):
    for x in y:
        if str(x) == "o":
            x = x.replace("o", "ko")
            z += x
        else:
            x = x.replace("k", "ok")
            z += x
        y = z
    z = ""
    print(y,c)
y = y.replace("k", " ")
y = y.count("oo")
print (y)
```

Source problem

> After ranting at length to a friend, Keith receives a message consisting of a single letter: "K". Incensed at this low-effort response, he responds with "OK", to which his friend replies "KOOK." An astute individual, Keith identifies the pattern instigated by his friend: subsequent messages consist of Keith and his friend replacing each "K" with "OK" and "O" with "KO". Help Keith find how many sets of consecutive Os of length two or greater are in the message on the 1000 reply. The first message, "K", does not count as a reply. Give your answer mod 10^9 + 7.
>
> To clarify what constitutes "sets of consecutive Os of length two or greater":
> KOKOOKOOOKOOOO - there are three sets of consecutive Ks of length two or greater in this string ("OO", "OOO", "OOOO").

Comment: What is "drag"? Does it take too much time?

Comment: Yes, it takes almost a full minute on my computer past 15 loops

Comment: You need a different algorithm.

Comment: Where did this problem come from?  You'll never write a program to solve it by brute force.  You start with `"ok"`, which has 2 characters.  After 1 iteration, you have 4.  Then 8, then 16, then 32 ... and after 1000 iterations `2**1001` characters.  All the computers on Earth combined don't have enough storage to hold that.

Comment: The problem is from a high school ctf, I didn't realize the scale of brute forcing it.

Comment: @TimPeters Probably homework or competitive programming. But that doesn't matter. Although OP should reference the problem source.

Comment: Added source problem

Comment: Uh... I didn't mean that. Probably I miscommunicateded something.

Comment: Well... I can't find definite meta consensus about that. I suggest rollback it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem here is that the number of letters doubles each step -- so, say, during the 40th step, there are 2^40 letters. If each letter takes one byte, that's about terabyte of letters. Of course, compared to how much space it would take to store all 1000 steps, that's only a tiny fraction. So, no, brute forcing the problem like this is not feasible.

Instead, the goal is likely to recognize that the pattern is the [Thue-Morse sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence#L-system), except sometimes flipped around. 'o' and 'k' correspond to either 0 or 1, it doesn't particularly matter. You can search the wikipedia page to find the maximum number of consecutive '1's in the sequence instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
y ="ok"
for c in range(1000):
    y = y.replace('o','ko')
    y = y.replace('k','ok')
    print(y,c)
```

you may not have to search in a loop for 'o' and 'k' replace will do it for you, still it will take a long time.

Comment: This is wrong. The `k` generated by the first replace will be replace again in the second `replace`.